# How to change a word on a line that has a certain string on it

Tags: xml, bash, sed

Ubuntu 16.04

I have a xml file that has about 50 lines of code. There is a certain line that contains the string "FFFedrs". ON this line is the word true.

If the structure was neat with only 1 space between like so ..

`<property name="FFFedrs" value="true"/> <!-- Enables/Disables EasyMoney -->`

I could use a sed in place command like this:

```
$ cat file.xml

<property name="FFFedrs" value="true"/> <!-- Enables/Disables EasyMoney -->

$ sed -i 's/<property\ name=\"FFFedrs\"\ value=\"true\"\/>\ <!--\ Enables\/Disables\ EasyMoney\ -->/<property\ name=\"FFFedrs\"\ value=\"false\"\/>\ <!--\ Enables\/Disables\ EasyMoney\ -->/g' file.xml
$
$ cat file.xml

<property name="FFFedrs" value="false"/> <!-- Enables/Disables EasyMoney -->
```

But the file is not neatly formatted so the line that has the string "FFFedrs" looks something like ...

```
 <property name="FFFedrs"              value="true"/>       <!-- Enables/Disables EasyMoney -->
```

How do I sed the true to false on the line that has the string "FFFedrs"

Comment: Don't Parse [X]HTML With Regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858. I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\+` after your spaces:

```
sed -i 's/<property\ \+name=\"FFFedrs\"\ \+value=\"true\"\/>/<property\ name=\"FFFedrs\"\ value=\"false\"\/>/g' file.xml
```

This will replaces multiple spaces with a single space.

If you want to preserve the spaces:

```
sed -i 's/<property\(\ \+\)name=\"FFFedrs\"\(\ \+\)value=\"true\"\/>/<property\1name=\"FFFedrs\"\2value=\"false\"\/>/g' file.xml
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Hats off to you mate.

Comment: @needtoknow, it might be because you have tab characters in there. Try to replace space character `\ ` with `[[:space:]]` in your regex, like this: `sed -i 's/<property[[:space:]]\+name=\"FFFedrs\"[[:space:]]\+value=\"true\"\/>/<property\ name=\"FFFedrs\"\ value=\"false\"\/>/g' file.xml`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
sed -i 's|\(<.*FFFedrs"\)\s*\(value.*>\)\s*\(<.*>\)|\1 \2 \3|' file
```

I use a pipe in sed as a separator because your line has slashes in.
3 groups of capture for the main values and output as wanted

You can use https://regex101.com/ to learn about regex and test it live.

Comment: Appreciate the help.